# Android studio wont show image when running emulator keeps throwing error

Tags: android, kotlin, google-developer-tools

I'm currently taking the google Kotlin coding course as part of their developer program and am following everything in their guide step by step. I've gotten to the part in the course where they ask us to download an image and add it as the background of the test app there showing us how to build. When the image downloads it is in the downloads folder; but when I add an `ImageView` and assign it the image file it keeps giving me the error shown in the attached image. Please help I cannot figure this out and I desperately want to learn.
[image: 1]

Comment: Hi @jamie4, keep up the passion to learn. This is a build error; first try going to top menu -> **Click File** and then ->  **Select Invalidate Cache/Restart** option. The Studio will start and refresh all files.

Comment: Add image in split mode where code can be viewed.